# Key=Val matching using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to match either `key` or `key=val` in python such that the resulting `groupdict()` from the `Match` object will either have `val` as `None` or have a value.

The following is close:

```
>>> regex = re.compile('(?P<key>[^=]+)=?(?P<val>.*)')
>>> regex.match('x=y').groupdict()
{'key': 'x', 'val': 'y'}            # yes!
>>> regex.match('x').groupdict()
{'key': 'x', 'val': ''}             # want None, not ''
```

But I want `val` to be `None` in the second case. I tried moving the optional `=` into the second group:

```
>>> regex = re.compile('(?P<key>[^=]+)(?P<val>=.+)?')
>>> regex.match('x').groupdict()
{'key': 'x', 'val': None}           # yes!
>>> regex.match('x=y').groupdict()
{'key': 'x', 'val': '=y'}           # don't want the =
```

That gives me the `None`, but then attaches the `=` to `val`. I also tried using the lookbehind with `(?<==)` but that didn't work for either expression. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an optional quantifier `?` to the `value` part so that it is matched zero or one time

```
>> regex = re.compile('(?P<key>[^=]+)(?:=(?P<val>.+))?')
>>> regex.match('x=y').groupdict()
{'key': 'x', 'val': 'y'}
>>> regex.match('x').groupdict()
{'key': 'x', 'val': None}
```

**Changes made**

- Moved the `=` to a non capturing group `(?:..)`
- `(?:=(?P<val>.+))?` Matched zero or one time. This is ensured by the `?`. That is it checks if `=value` can be matched (capturing only the value part). If not `None` is captured.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
regex = re.compile('(?P<key>[^=]+)(?:=(?P<val>.*))?')
```

Edited the regex

Test 1 :  'x=y' , then key='x' and val='y'

Test 2 :  'x=' , then key='x' and val=''

Test 3 :  'x' , then key='x' and val=None